# Count number of days table has had no data ingested, and keep list for all tables, remove from list once data has been ingested

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery, insert, sql-update

I have this query:

```
    (SELECT table_id, dataset_ID
    FROM `list_of_tables`
    WHERE table_id NOT IN 
         (SELECT table_id 
          FROM list_of_tables 
          WHERE ingestion_time = CURRENT_DATE())
          GROUP BY table_id, dataset_ID)
```

It gives me a list of tables that have not had any ingested data for the current date. I want to be able to have a list of all tables that have had no ingested data currently and how many days in a row since the last date of ingested data. But once data has been ingested remove it from the list.

EX:

| Table ID | Days without data ingested |
| --- | --- |
| Product | 3 |
| User | 4 |

Lets say the next day product gets data ingested into it, and Users and Building gets no data ingested. The table should now look like this.

| Table ID | Days without data ingested |
| --- | --- |
| Building | 1 |
| User | 5 |

Where product now has been removed, User has been added one more day since its been 5 days, and Building now shows up with 1 day without any data ingested.

I need help with the logic/query for this situation. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below approach:

```
with list_of_tables as (
select 'Product' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-01') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'Product' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-02') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'Product' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-03') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'User' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-03') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'User' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-04') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'User' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-05') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'User' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-06') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'Product' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-16') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'Building' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-15') as ingestion_time,
union all select 'User' as table_id, 'dataset1' as dataset_ID, date('2022-06-15') as ingestion_time,

),

with_diff as (
select 
  table_id, 
  array_agg(date_diff(current_date(),ingestion_time,day)) as day_diff, 
from list_of_tables
group by 1
)

select 
  table_id,
  array_length(day_diff) as days_without_data 
from with_diff
  where 0 not in unnest(day_diff)
```

Output:

[image]

If the last 3 rows of the sample data will be removed, the result will be:

[image]